# using javascript new regexp object for brackets containing set of matching characters

Tags: javascript, regex

So looks like I have ran into a weird problem and was wondering whether somebody has a solution for it or am I misusing the RegExp object in javascript. I've written down a regexp which checks whether a particular value is alphanumeric or not. The function and some sample test cases are as follows

```
var re = new RegExp("^[a-zA-z\\d]+$");

document.writeln(re.test("a")); 
document.writeln(re.test("a1234")); 
document.writeln(re.test("12345a"));
document.writeln(re.test("12345"));
document.writeln(re.test("a["));
document.writeln(re.test("[]"));
document.writeln(re.test("]"));
```

In all the cases, it returns a true. I tried escaping the brackets in the regular exp i.e `var re = new RegExp("^\\[a-zA-z\\d\\]+$");` but then every test case returns false.

I fixed this problem by using a regex literal instead like `var re = /^[a-zA-Z\d]+$/;`. I think I could have used `\w` but the field should not contain the `_` character.

Does anybody know how to fix the problem or is the RegExp object not compatible with a set of matching characters??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the regex and this is the normal behaviour. It's just that `A-z` has more characters than just letters, which you can see when you look at a character chart.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second 'z' should be 'Z'. The ascii range between Z (0x5a) and a (0x61) includes the square brackets, the caret, backquote, and underscore.

Comment: seems like a facepalm moment to me, thanks for the correction